# main-bower-files gulp returns empty array

Tags: bower, gulp, gulp-inject

I'm trying to use the plugin `main-bower-files`  and it doesn't seem to be able to pull the directory from bower_components.

Its debug message shows it has the right files, but it doesn't return an array

```
#here you can see the debug finding the places
PackageCollection add        angular bower_components/angular
PackageCollection add        json3 bower_components/json3
PackageCollection add        es5-shim bower_components/es5-shim
PackageCollection add        jquery bower_components/jquery
PackageCollection add        angular-resource bower_components/angular-resource
PackageCollection add        angular-cookies bower_components/angular-cookies
PackageCollection add        angular-sanitize bower_components/angular-sanitize
PackageCollection add        angular-animate bower_components/angular-animate
PackageCollection add        angular-touch bower_components/angular-touch
PackageCollection add        angular-ui-router bower_components/angular-ui-router

[22:25:31] [] #< this is the result of calling require('main-bower-files')()
```

heres my gulp task for inject

```
var bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files')


gulp.task('inject', function() {
  util.log(bowerFiles({debugging:true}))
  gulp.src('app/index.jade')
    .pipe(jade({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles()), {starttag: '<!-- inject:{{ext}}-->', endtag: '<!-- endinject-->'}))
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src('.tmp/**/*.js', {read: false}), {starttag: '<!-- inject:files:{{ext}}-->', endtag: '<!-- endinject-->'}))
    .pipe(connect.reload())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
})
```

Comment: I have exactly the same trouble, using macOS and gulp 3.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Bower and run `Bower install`

So :

- Install Node and npm, I guess it's done
- run `npm install` to make your project npm ready and install what is in **package.json**
- install bower : `sudo npm install -g bower`
- run `bower install` to copy your **bower.json** dependencies in `./bower_components` directory
- install gulp : `npm install -g gulp`
- build your project : `gulp build`
- check it out : `gulp serve` and you're ready for it

Well, *almost* automatic build...

Answer (score 3):

If you have dependencies as devDependencies in `bower.json` you need to add '  `includeDev:true`

see

> includeDev
> Type: mixed Default: false
>
> You can include your devDependencies in two ways:
>
> Set this option to inclusive or true to add the devDependencies to your >dependencies
> or use exclusive to exclude your dependencies

Comment: And also includeSelf if you want your own files to be added, it is false by default. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files